# C++ compiling files

Tags: c++, compilation, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class called LibItem, and two inherited classes called Book and DVD. I have made the .h and .cpp files for each of these classes.

I am now wanting to do some code in main to use these files.

Currently, I am just 'including' the .h files at the top of my main code.
This is not working.

Do I need to compile these files before using them? If so, how do I do this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef BookH
#define BookH

class Book : public LibItem
{
public:
    Book(const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&);
    void setISBN(const std::string&);
    std::string getISBN();
    void PrintDetails();

private:
    Book();
    std::string ISBN;

};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
[BCC32 Error] Book.h(7): E2303 Type name expected
[BCC32 Error] Book.h(9): E2090 Qualifier 'std' is not a class or namespace name
[BCC32 Error] Book.h(9): E2293 ) expected
[BCC32 Error] Book.h(10): E2090 Qualifier 'std' is not a class or namespace name
```

Can I please have some help with these errors?

Comment: In general, yes, and how depends on your compiler and/or build system.

Comment: tell us which a build system or compiler you use

Comment: I am using C++ Builder. The files I have are LibItem.h, LibItem.cpp, Book,h, Book.cpp, DVD.h, DVD.cpp

Comment: OK, I have added the relevant files to the project, yet am getting some errors. I have updated my post reflecting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include all.h files which contains declaration you want to use in your main file. Also, you have to add all .cpp files to your project/makefile/etc to compile it, because .h files aren't compilation units...